# Drawing shapes with random colors

Tags: android, user-interface, shapes

Fairly new to ui for android, searched a lot but was not able to find a solution for my problem.

Goal:
I want to show random shapes with random colors on the screen.

My approach so far was to create buttons and set the shapes(xml) as background. That works fine but I have trouble changing the color of the shape. Also, it seems a little off to create buttons only to show shapes.

What would be the best approach to create a shape (e.g square,triangle etc.), give it a random color from colors.xml and finally display it?

Answer (score 1):

You create your own custom View and use the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method to draw circles, rectangles, triangles to the `canvas` object by calling the following `Canvas` classes methods:

- drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint)
- drawOval(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)
- drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)

And to change the colors you can use the `Paint` class by setting different colors to it, just like below:

```
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Here is a very simple custom `View` class that I made that draws shapes with different color:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Arlind on 09-Dec-15.
 */
public class ArlindCustomView extends View
{
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public ArlindCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ArlindCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public ArlindCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(300,100,50,paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(80,90,70,paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(200, 200, 250, 250, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawRect(300, 300, 350, 350, paint);
    }

}
```

You can add this class to your xml or programmatically.